# Converting a Mongo Collection to GridFS?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Currently, my website is using a `Mongo.Collection` to hold data submitted from another site. Strings are sent over through HTTP methods and packed into the collection afterward. However, this collection now needs to support storing larger files, but still needs to hold the data already stored, so I've been looking into converting the collection into GridFS. Is there a way to attach the data onto empty files as metadata, or is the conversion more convoluted than this?